# Matlab: Forcing pixel values to NaN that are corresponding to non-zeros in a mask

Tags: matlab, image-processing, nan

I am experimenting to correct edge artifacts in partly finished RGB images like [half5](https://www.flickr.com/photos/gbachelier/45613023272), the right half of a p31m image tiling, with different methods like inpainting with  [inpaint_nans](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551-inpaint_nans). Because the position of the edges are analytically known I first draw a gray mask the same size with insertShape [outmask_h](https://www.flickr.com/photos/gbachelier/30722943477). Now I want to force those pixels from half5 to NaN that are corresponding to the non-zero pixels of outmask_h to get the NaNs necessary for inpaint_nans so I tried

```
[r,c] = find(outmask_h);                                                
for i = 1:length(r); half5(r(i),c(i)) = NaN; end
```

I first thought this was ok because writing the result shows black pixels where the mask is non-zero but the result after inpaint_nans looks the same as before and counting the NaNs in one of the channels delivers 0 so this is wrong (why?).

The opposite strategy (generating a NaN array and replacing the zero pixels) seems to work BUT is much too slow

```
half5n = NaN(size(half5,1), size(half5,2), 3);
[r,c] = find(outmask_h==0);
for i = 1:length(r); half5n(r(i),c(i)) = half5(r(i),c(i)); end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `outmask_h` array as a `logical` index (ensure that it's `logical` first) and then apply that to each channel of the image before passing it to `inpaint_nans`.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, be sure that your input matrix is `double` otherwise the assignment with `NaN` values will result in `0`'s

```
half5 = double(half5);

mask = logical(outmask_h);

new = zeros(size(half5));

for k = 1:size(half5, 3)
    channel = half5(:, :, k);
    channel(mask) = NaN;

    new(:,:,k) = inpaint_nans(channel);
end
```

If you instead want to turn the non-zeros to `NaN` you can use the inverse of `outmask_h`

```
mask = ~outmask_h;
```

Comment: @Suewer: I got: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. possibly because the mask is gray and not binary

Comment: @GünterBachelier See my updates. Also, `half5` is an RGB image correct?

Comment: @Suewer: I tried        rgb_mask = repmat(outmask_h, [1, 1, 3]);
        half5n = half5; 
        half5n(logical(rgb_mask)) = NaN; but I get "Attempt to grow array along ambiguous dimension."

Comment: @GünterBachelier What is the result of `size(half5)`?

Comment: @GünterBachelier What is the size of `outmask_h`?

Comment: no errors with: outmask_h = im2bw(outmask_h); 
        rgb_mask = repmat(outmask_h, [1, 1, 3]);
        half5n = half5; 
        half5n(rgb_mask) = NaN; but no inpainting result ergo no NaNs in half5n

Comment: @GünterBachelier The documentation for `inpaint_nans` does mention that it only works on 2D arrays (your RGB image is 3D)

Comment: @GünterBachelier: Also make sure that `half5` is a floating-point type and not an integer type. `half5=double(half5);`. You can not write NaN to an integer array.

Comment: before inpainting I make it double half6 = double(half5n); else inpaint_nans shows an error. inaint_nans is working on channels like: for i=1:3; half6(:,:,i) = inpaint_nans(half6(:,:,i),5); end; This is all working, the problem is forcing the NaNs before inpainting.

Comment: @GünterBachelier: Make it `double` **before** inserting the NaNs. Insert the NaNs into a `double` image, not a `uint8` image.

Comment: I multiple checked size of image and mask but I always get the same error; Attempt to grow array along ambiguous dimension.
Error in img2symgroup_1_13>img2wallpapergroup (line 1044)
            channel(mask_h) = NaN;

Comment: if I am using mask_h = im2bw(outmask_h) instead logical() it works!!

Comment: @GünterBachelier Just curious, what is the output of `unique(outmask_h(:))`?

Comment: mask_h=unique(...); Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
Error in img2symgroup_1_13>img2wallpapergroup (line 1052)
            channel(mask_h) = NaN;